# Setting up static ip for a hotspot using connman

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot

I have OSMC installed on a pi3 and it has connman as the network manager.

I keep the pi3 connected to internet using a lan cable and run a hotspot using the wifi.

Now, sometimes when the pi reboots, it assigns some random ip to itself on the wifi interface.

---

How can I configure the pi to run the hotspot with a fixed ip?

and/or

How can I setup some domain name, so that when i type in domain address(for example www.domain.local) on my laptop, which is connected to the hotspot, it should open up the page for the service running on port, say 4321, on the raspberry Pi?

Comment: I know it's old but did you find a solution?